# Using Find.Execute within a loop in Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I have a range which I have set, let's call it `myRange`. I also have an array of short strings, let's call it `searchArray`.

I want to search within `myRange` for all instances of each of the strings, and change the text color.

The issue I am having is how to reset the range each time after executing the search.

This what I am currently attempting:

```
Dim searchRange as Range

For i = 1 to UBound(searchArray)
  Set searchRange = myRange
  With searchRange.Find
    .Text = searchArray(i)
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindStop
    .Execute

    While .Found
      .Parent.Font.Color = RGB(20,20,20)
      .Execute
    Wend
  End With
Next i
```

However, executing the find not only changes `searchRange` but also `myRange`, so that when I loop back I am not searching what I want.

How can I reset `searchRange` to be the original `myRange` on each loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
Set searchRange = myRange
```

do this:

```
Set searchRange = myRange.Duplicate
```

This way your `searchRange` will be independent from `myRange`, as stated in the documentation on [`Range.Duplicate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837543.aspx):

> By duplicating a **Range** object, you can change the starting or ending character position of the duplicate range without changing the original range.